# Identifying and/or stopping contact form spammers (possibly from intranet)?

Tags: forms, jsp, spam, intranet

a situation has recently come up at work that leaves me grasping at straws for solutions...

Our main webpage employs a built-in contact form that allows our users to contact us (to prevent our email address from being harvested and whatnot). Our application is available over the internet but a large portion of its visitors come from the company's intranet. Our form already uses validation for email address format, collects username (if logged in) information, browser info, and etc.

A few days ago, we started to receive threatening messages from an unknown sender. This kind of behavior is a misuse of technology per company policy. So my question to you guys is:

**1)How can/could I identify an intranet user and get details such as their internal IP/mac address? (ActiveX/applets?)**

**2)How can I help prevent these types of inappropriate messages from being sent? Keyword filtering? I'd use captchas but most likely a human is doing the spamming.**

Extra info: our server runs Apache Tomcat and the application is written in Java(JSP).